# Responsive column for login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a login form that is responsive. I want the forms on the left, and a logo on the right using bootstrap columns, but it does not seem to work. Here is the source code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <br />

            <input type="text" name="usern" placeholder="Username" />
            <br /><br />
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <img src="../Content/edman_logo.png">
</div> 
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you attached the output which you're getting from this code ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if `column` is in use for Bootstrap 4.2.1. Since you provided an incomplete snippet you can try adding a `container` and switching `column` to `col` which is in the Bootstrap 4 [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/).

Additionally, the code you are using looks like it was copy and pasted from another form. I have included the styles and labels necessary for it to align with Bootstrap's out of the box styling. Check out the codepen below to see a Bootstrap example using the code you provided.

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <hr>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="usern">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="Username" name="usern" id="usern" placeholder="Username" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pass">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="login" value="Login">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <img src="../Content/edman_logo.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example Codepen: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/gqxyQy

Comment: Not sure if 'column' is still in use for Bootstrap-4. Someone can correct me if I am wrong. But this will give you the layout you requested.

Comment: Please add some explanatory notes (it will make your answer better).

Comment: Yes, that code was copy pasted from my previous php project because I thought that it would be a compatible code with ASP. I'm pretty new at the language and I'm still trying to figure out what works and what doesn't. I'll try your code brooksrelyt. Thank you.

EDIT: Tried the code and the same output still shows.

Comment: What do you mean by output? Layout or some other php function output?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Login</legend>
          <br />

          <input type="text" name="usern" placeholder="Username" />
          <br /><br />
          <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
          <br /><br />
          <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="logo">
      <img src="../Content/edman_logo.png">
    </div>   
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS Classes

```
.logo{
  float: right;
}
.col{
  float: left;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/o4b0pgvq/